# Drupal 7: How do I get altered values from a preprocess function back to the render function?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to make a simple Panels module. I have a form with text fields were I can enter value, then that value prints to the .tpl file, via a render function, eg:

```
function my_module_panel_render($subtype, $conf, $args, $contexts) {

  $block = new stdClass();

  $block->content = [
    '#theme' => 'my_tpl',
    '#config' => $conf,
  ];

  return $block;
}
```

Then on .tpl:

```
<?php print $config['name_field']; ?>
```

This works fine.

But I want to alter the value slightly. I've learnt I need a `hook_preprocess_theme()` function, which I have added.

But then how do I actually go about altering the values? How do I then return the altered value to $conf?

Doing something like

```
$conf['name_field'] = $conf['name_field'] . $some_other_stuff;
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Would anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

OK, what I didn't relise was that `$conf` was a sub-array of the `$variables` array, which `hook_preprocess_theme()` takes as a parameter, as seen on my `hook_theme`:

```
function my_module_theme() {
  return [
    'my_module' => [
      'template' => 'theme/my_theme',
      'render element' => 'element',
      'variables' => [
        'config' => NULL,
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

So, my `hook_preprocess_theme()` function now looks like:

```
function my_module_preprocess_my_theme(&$vars) {
  $conf = $vars['config'];
  $vars['config']['name_field'] = $conf['name_field'] . $some_other_stuff;
}
```